# Travis CI is failing to run tests with **/*_test.rb pattern

Tags: ruby, rspec, travis-ci, minitest

My micro Ruby project tests works on my machine, on private VM, but fails on Travis CI bulid

Project uses both `rspec` (+`rspec-given`) and `minitest`

Full trace here: https://travis-ci.org/equivalent/code_katas/jobs/61321482

```
    $ bundle exec rake
    MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From     /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby
    2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
    /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:676:in `<class:Runner>': undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:261:in `<module:Unit>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/build/equivalent/code_katas/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sorcerer-1.0.2/test/sorcerer/resource_test.rb:3:in `require'
    #...
```

The error is self-explanatory `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test`. This is caused by `rspec-given` dependency `sorcerer` using `test-unit` ([source](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer/blob/master/test/sorcerer/resource_test.rb)) (My code is not referring to `test-unit` anywhere in the code)

So the thing I'm curious about is if anyone know how to get around this.

Like I said it works everywhere else except Travis CI

Comment: do you have `require 'minitest/given'` in your spec_helper?

Comment: failing that - go have a look into the source code for respec-given: https://github.com/jimweirich/rspec-given and see where it's using `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` - fork the repo, change it to `Minitest::Test` and make a pull-request (and use your fork in the meantime)

Comment: thx for reply, I've tried to add/remove `require 'minitest/given' didn't work. I dig around the sourcecode of rspec-given, there is no reference to `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` . The reason why this is happening is that Travis CI is for some reason evaluating `sorcerer` gem tests as a part of my app. Because I'm running MiniTest > 5.0  and sorcerer's Test::Unit they are not compatible https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/283   one solution might be to lock to MiniTest 4.x however I want to use the latest. (which works but not on Travis CI)

Comment: it seems this is because  my project `Rakefile` is running tests with pattern `**/*_test.rb` (usaly developers use `test/**/*_test.rb`) https://github.com/equivalent/code_katas/blob/master/Rakefile    , yet I want to run tests in all folders of the project

Comment: ok got it now :) answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Travis CI is cloning repository into  `/home/travis/build/username/projectname` and then `bundle install` with
`--deployment` flag which install gems to `vendor` folder

`/home/travis/build/username/projectname/verdor`

my `Rakefile` was using test pattern `**/*_test.rb` therefore run tests in all folders, therefore it was loading verdor directory and all the tests from dependencies (external gems) some of which were `TestUnit` not compatible with `MiniTest`

solution was to load tests in Rakefile not with `pattern` but with:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t| 
  t.test_files = Dir['**/*_test.rb'].reject do |path|
    path.include?('vendor')  # tell travis CI to ignore vendor tests
  end 
end
```

similar apply for RSpec

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t| 
  t.pattern = Dir.glob('**/*_spec.rb').reject do |path|
    path.include?('vendor')  # tell travis CI to ignore vendor tests
  end 
  # t.rspec_opts = '--format documentation'
end
```